# Raise PreviewKeyDown in element contentcontrol of Combobox

Tags: wpf, combobox

I have a multiselectCombobox. I want to open it when press down key and focus on Textbox. then press down key on it, focus on items in item source.

I use [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/563862/Multi-Select-ComboBox-in-WPF). But i add a Textbox on popup for search in list.

I add a `PreviewKeyDown` on UserControl ,

```
private void UserControl_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Down)
        {
            var toggle = (ToggleButton)MultiSelectCombo.Template.FindName("ToggleButton", MultiSelectCombo);
            var txt = (TextBox)MultiSelectCombo.Template.FindName("searchTextBox", MultiSelectCombo);
            toggle.IsChecked = true;
            txt.Focus();
        }

    }
```

when control is focus and user press down key, opened popup and focus textbox.

I want to focus items when press down key in Textbox, i raise PreviewKeyDown of TextBox but raise key down of UserControl and focuse on Textbox.

How do resolve it?

[image]

**Edit**

I use this code but focuse on Textbox only.

[image]

Comment: After reading your question multiple times, I can't understand your question fully. Try to convey your requirement using an image.

Comment: I add image , plz see it

Comment: By posting Image, I mean describe your problem using image. Your current image doesn't help much.

Comment: I want to keyboard base my control, when user focus on MyControl, i want to open popup when press down key and focus search textbox, when focus on searchtexbox and press down key , focus on items.

Answer (score 0):

`PreviewKeyDown` is tunnel routed event, so you cant catch `PreviewKeyDown` on TextBox before catch it on UserControl.
So, you should build your logic like

```
private void UserControl_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (!ComboBoxTest.IsFocused)
    {
        ComboBoxTest.Focus();
    }
    else if (ComboBoxTest.IsFocused)
    {
    }
}
```